# How I can get image Uri from gallery for a long time?

Tags: java, android, path, uri, gallery

I'm a junior in android development and I faced a problem with getting Uri for a long time. My aim is get an Image Uri and show the image after few days. I use this method and it works when I restart my app, but in doesn't work when I try to upload image using the same Uri after a day. What i should do to get long Uri?

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);


 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            save(uri.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: your problem is not quite clear, you say it's working when you restart the app, but what is not working ?

Comment: @Maelig I can't get the image from Uri after a long period of time, but it works for a couple of hours after I save the Uri.

Comment: Where are you saving the Uri?

Comment: @VivekSingh in a SQlite database

Comment: what's the error ? Is the file still in place ? Is your image gallery app generating temporary links ? Please log a URI to see what's like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of this URL refers to a local image and I think  will not work if you removed this image or renamed it,

you can transform it to base64 and save it in shared preferences or local DB.

Comment: I am not doing anything with the image, however it isn't working properly(